# Strange rigging problem

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

I am modelling a gun, and used an armature to manipulate the bullet chain with an IK target at the very end. I used this to manipulate the chain into the desired position, but for some reason a single vertice has shot off into the distance or something. When i go into edit mode the chain returns to it's natural mesh position, so I can't find out which one is doing this. I've tried using weight paint but I don't think that's working.

Here's a rendered version,

[image: Here's a rendered version,]

One in solid,

[image: One in solid,]

One in weight paint

[image: One in weight paint]

and a closeup on the problem area

[image: and a closeup on the problem area.]

I wasn't sure what to actually search online to find a solution, so I came here.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - After doing a bit of weight painting on the root of the "spike", it went back to normal.